# form_for tag with conditions + rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I have a form_for tag and I want to enable its `:remote => true` option upon the user status

```
if the current user is not an admin I want the form to be :remote => true
if the current user is an admin I want the form to be a default form
```

This is what I came up with and its nowt working ;(

```
<%= form_for @school, ((:remote => true) unless current_user.admin?) ,  :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

can some one help me

I'm on

```
ruby 1.9
Rails 3.2.x
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Helper method with the following

```
def form_remote_or_not(user, object, &block)
    if user.admin?
        form_for object, :remote => true, &block
    else
        form_for object, &block
    end
end
```

As for your view file; `<%= form_remote_or_not(current_user, @school) do |f| %>`